# How to remove border of last row of table

Tags: html, css

I want to remove border of last row of table so that it will look like 
table is completed in second last row itself.

I have tried this by making table border='0' in CSS and then giving border='1' for every tr except last row. It is working perfectly in chrome and safari but not in IE11.

Is there any better way to do it so that it will support in IE11 as well ?

Comment: Where is your code? Maybe you can do something like table row:last-child {border:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `:last-of-type` suedo-selector.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#noEndBorder tr:last-of-type {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table id="noEndBorder">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**
Updated the code to reflect multiple tables, but only one showing no border at the end.

https://jsfiddle.net/venLzgq5/1/

Comment: there are multiple tables on page and i want to remove border for only one table. If i do it by tr tag it will hide all table's last  tr.

Comment: Hows that possible ? When you have  proper id to  trace that particular table  just go for that table   and  that tr.